How to correctly mock API call in GO with httptest?
I have this function which uses an SDK package for Openstack.
import (
    "github.com/gophercloud/gophercloud"
    "github.com/gophercloud/gophercloud/openstack"
)    

func Authenticate() (*gophercloud.ProviderClient, error) {
        // Get some options
        authOpts, err := openstack.AuthOptionsFromEnv()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // HERE: Would like to mock this api request
        provider, err := openstack.AuthenticatedClient(authOpts)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    
        // Set a 60-second timeout
        provider.HTTPClient = http.Client{
            Timeout: 60 * time.Second,
        }
  
        return provider, nil
    }

Using httptest if I understand from this snippet of code, needs me to pass server.URL coming from a new server server := httptest.NewServer(...), but openstack.AuthenticatedClient(authOpts) is just a preconfigured function that I'm just calling. I don't know how to inject server.URL to mock this call (and return some fixed value).
This is supposed to be how its done:
func TestGetFixedValue(t *testing.T) {
   server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
       if r.URL.Path != "/fixedvalue" {
           t.Errorf("Expected to request '/fixedvalue', got: %s", r.URL.Path)
       }
       if r.Header.Get("Accept") != "application/json" {
           t.Errorf("Expected Accept: application/json header, got: %s", r.Header.Get("Accept"))
       }
       w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
       w.Write([]byte(`{"value":"fixed"}`))
   }))
   defer server.Close()
 
   value, _ := GetFixedValue(server.URL)
   if value != "fixed" {
       t.Errorf("Expected 'fixed', got %s", value)
   }
}


You could use an instance of http.Client with its Transport field set to an instance of an object implementing http.RoundTripper and doing with the request(s) that OpenStack package performs whatever you wish.

But http.Client is, at least how I understand it, used after the API call to simply set the timeout options. Whatever I do with http.Client needs to happen before the call, right?

Ah, yes, you're correct. OK, in this case you could look at the IdentityEndpoint field of the authOpts (its of the type github.com/gophercloud/gophercloud@v2.AuthOptions).

Rewrite your function so you can mock the call:
func Authenticate(
    providerClient func(gophercloud.AuthOptions) (*gophercloud.ProviderClient, error),
) (*gophercloud.ProviderClient, error) {
    // Get some options
    authOpts, err := openstack.AuthOptionsFromEnv()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // HERE: Would like to mock this api request
    provider, err := providerClient(authOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Set a 60-second timeout
    provider.HTTPClient = http.Client{
        Timeout: 60 * time.Second,
    }

    return provider, nil
}

You can call it regularly with:
    c, err := Authenticate(openstack.AuthenticatedClient)

and mock it with:
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // ...
    }))
    defer server.Close()

    mockClient := func(gophercloud.AuthOptions) (*gophercloud.ProviderClient, error) {
        return openstack.NewClient(server.URL)
    }
    c, err := Authenticate(mockClient)

